# How to do research using local resources remotely?

Tags: united-states, research-methods

My great great great grandfather spent some of his life in Houghton, Houghton, Michigan, United States, and I would like to find more records for that area regarding his family. The problem is that I live in Utah and cannot make a trip myself.

I can call the local library, but would they be willing to send me the information I need?  What is the best way to get research done from such a far distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all libraries have the same staff support or policies. Sometimes, the library staffing and policies are reported on their website.

Many of the public libraries I contact are able to provide information for postage or a small fee. In several towns, a genealogical society mans the genealogy section only on some days--once a week, or twice a month.

There are other alternatives to long distance research, too, ranging from look up volunteers to professional genealogists.

P.S. If you are inquiring about a book or generally *published* material, check [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/) to learn if a library near you carries the work. If it doesn't, inquire whether the book is available by inter-library loan. (I believe that sometimes WorldCat reports whether or not inter-library loan is offered on the item.)

Comment: Are there any websites that said volunteers or professional genealogists might be found at?

Comment: The Association of Professional Genealogists's website has an online searchable roster. http://www.apgen.org/directory/index.html The local genealogical society (or library) may have names of those to whom they refer you. You might check the US GenWeb site, too.

Answer (score 9):

I've successfully found researchers via http://genlighten.com to do research in local repositories for me.  And although I've never used it, I've heard Random Acts of Genealogical Kindness was a good site.  It appears to still be down (source: [RAOGK wiki](http://raogk.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Acts_of_Genealogical_Kindness_Wiki)), but you could try [their Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/raogkUSA/members/) if you are on FB.

Comment: I just wish I could mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: @david.tanner Compliment appreciated!  [This discussion on a related issue](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/why-are-we-accepting-answers-so-fast?cb=1) may be of interest...

Answer (score 4):

Searching the web for genealogical or historical societies in either the town or the county is helpful.  I've found that local societies frequently have data that will never appear in a library and since they are usually volunteer organizations, are understanding of your needs.  I belong to several societies in areas I will probably never visit, but their staff and newsletters keep me informed when they have created indices of B/M/D.  It usually costs less than $30 to join.

Comment: Lynda, you might also want to contribute to http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-helpful-will-joining-my-local-genealogical-society-be-if-my-family-research

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to check state-level resources, which may include digitized local materials.  Start by exploring the resources linked from

http://www.digitalstatearchives.com/michigan

Comment: In all my searching, I haven't found that one!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the records have been digitised you could visit your local Church of Latter day Saints research centre and order the microfilms.

Comment: It probably does appear that the question and answers were narrowly focused. That is probably because of the question and dialog about a related, earlier question. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/248/help-tracing-ancestor-back-to-germany